# Create table with more than 12 column

Tags: bootstrap-4

I create a table with 17 column and it out of bootstrap grid 12
How can I create the table responsive without the scroll bar?
attached image to show the result of code  and to show the problem
Note please 
There is sidebar menu at the design and it take space from the width of screen

```html
    <table id="tablePreview" class="table table-hover table-sm" >
                                        <!--Table head-->
                                          <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th>Tooth #</th>
                                              <th>ur 8</th>
                                              <th>ur 7</th>
                                              <th>ur 6</th>
                                              <th>ur 5</th>
                                              <th>ur 4</th>
                                              <th>ur 3</th>
                                              <th>ur 2</th>
                                              <th>ur 1</th>
                                              <th>ul 1</th>
                                              <th>ul 2</th>
                                              <th>ul 3</th>
                                              <th>ul 4</th>
                                              <th>ul 5</th>
                                              <th>ul 6</th>
                                              <th>ul 7</th>
                                              <th>ul 8</th>
                                             </tr>
                                          </thead>
                                          <!--Table head-->
                                          <!--Table body-->
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th  scope='row'>Image</th>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                        <img id="img_plr_8_1" src="images/pr8.png" alt="present LR8" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_elr_8_4" src="images/er8.png" alt="Endo LR8" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_ilr_8_5" src="images/ir8.png" alt="Implant LR8" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_nclr_8_2" src="images/ncr8.png" alt="Not Caries LR8" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_clr_8_3" src="images/cr8.png" alt="Caries LR8" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                        <img id="img_plr_7_1" src="images/pr7.png" alt="present LR7" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_elr_7_4" src="images/er7.png" alt="Endo LR7" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_ilr_7_5" src="images/ir7.png" alt="Implant LR7" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_nclr_7_2" src="images/ncr7.png" alt="Not Caries LR7" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_clr_7_3" src="images/cr7.png" alt="Caries LR7" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                        <img id="img_plr_6_1" src="images/pr6.png" alt="present LR6" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_elr_6_4" src="images/er6.png" alt="Endo LR6" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_ilr_6_5" src="images/ir6.png" alt="Implant LR6" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_nclr_6_2" src="images/ncr6.png" alt="Not Caries LR6" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_clr_6_3" src="images/cr6.png" alt="Caries LR6" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                        <img id="img_plr_5_1" src="images/pr5.png" alt="present LR5" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_elr_5_4" src="images/er5.png" alt="Endo LR5" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_ilr_5_5" src="images/ir5.png" alt="Implant LR5" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_nclr_5_2" src="images/ncr5.png" alt="Not Caries LR5" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_clr_5_3" src="images/cr5.png" alt="Caries LR5" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                        <img id="img_plr_4_1" src="images/pr4.png" alt="present LR4" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_elr_4_4" src="images/er4.png" alt="Endo LR4" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_ilr_4_5" src="images/ir4.png" alt="Implant LR4" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_nclr_4_2" src="images/ncr4.png" alt="Not Caries LR4" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_clr_4_3" src="images/cr4.png" alt="Caries LR4" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;"> 
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                        <img id="img_plr_3_1" src="images/pr3.png" alt="present LR3" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_elr_3_4" src="images/er3.png" alt="Endo LR3" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_ilr_3_5" src="images/ir3.png" alt="Implant LR3" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_nclr_3_2" src="images/ncr3.png" alt="Not Caries LR3" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_clr_3_3" src="images/cr3.png" alt="Caries LR3" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                        <img id="img_plr_2_1" src="images/pr2.png" alt="present LR2" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_elr_2_4" src="images/er2.png" alt="Endo LR2" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_ilr_2_5" src="images/ir2.png" alt="Implant LR2" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_nclr_2_2" src="images/ncr2.png" alt="Not Caries LR2" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_clr_2_3" src="images/cr2.png" alt="Caries LR2" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                        <img id="img_plr_1_1" src="images/pr1.png" alt="present LR1" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_elr_1_4" src="images/er1.png" alt="Endo LR1" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_ilr_1_5" src="images/ir1.png" alt="Implant LR1" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_nclr_1_2" src="images/ncr1.png" alt="Not Caries LR1" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                        <img id="img_clr_1_3" src="images/cr1.png" alt="Caries LR1" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                      <img id="img_pll_1_1" src="images/pl1.png" alt="present LL1" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ell_1_4" src="images/el1.png" alt="Endo LL1" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ill_1_5" src="images/il3.png" alt="Implant LL1" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ncll_1_2" src="images/ncl1.png" alt="Not Caries LL1" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_cll_1_3" src="images/cl1.png" alt="Caries LL1" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                      <img id="img_pll_2_1" src="images/pl2.png" alt="present LL2" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ell_2_4" src="images/el3.png" alt="Endo LL2" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ill_2_5" src="images/il4.png" alt="Implant LL2" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ncll_2_2" src="images/ncl2.png" alt="Not Caries LL2" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_cll_2_3" src="images/cl2.png" alt="Caries LL2" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">                                                                                              
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                      <img id="img_pll_3_1" src="images/pl3.png" alt="present LL3" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ell_3_4" src="images/el3.png" alt="Endo LL3" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ill_3_5" src="images/il5.png" alt="Implant LL3" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ncll_3_2" src="images/ncl3.png" alt="Not Caries LL3" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_cll_3_3" src="images/cl3.png" alt="Caries LL3" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                      <img id="img_pll_4_1" src="images/pl4.png" alt="present LL4" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ell_4_4" src="images/el4.png" alt="Endo LL4" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ill_4_5" src="images/il6.png" alt="Implant LL4" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ncll_4_2" src="images/ncl4.png" alt="Not Caries LL4" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_cll_4_3" src="images/cl4.png" alt="Caries LL4" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                      <img id="img_pll_5_1" src="images/pl5.png" alt="present LL5" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ell_5_4" src="images/el5.png" alt="Endo LL5" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ill_5_5" src="images/il7.png" alt="Implant LL5" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ncll_5_2" src="images/ncl5.png" alt="Not Caries LL5" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_cll_5_3" src="images/cl5.png" alt="Caries LL5" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                      <img id="img_pll_6_1" src="images/pl6.png" alt="present LL6" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ell_6_4" src="images/el4.png" alt="Endo LL6" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ill_6_5" src="images/il8.png" alt="Implant LL6" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ncll_6_2" src="images/ncl6.png" alt="Not Caries LL6" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_cll_6_3" src="images/cl6.png" alt="Caries LL6" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                      <img id="img_pll_7_1" src="images/pl7.png" alt="present LL7" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ell_7_4" src="images/el7.png" alt="Endo LL7" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ill_7_5" src="images/il1.png" alt="Implant LL7" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ncll_7_2" src="images/ncl7.png" alt="Not Caries LL7" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_cll_7_3" src="images/cl7.png" alt="Caries LL7" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='position: relative; height :290px'>
                                                      <img id="img_pll_8_1" src="images/pl8.png" alt="present LL8" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ell_8_4" src="images/el8.png" alt="Endo LL8" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ill_8_5" src="images/il2.png" alt="Implant LL8" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_ncll_8_2" src="images/ncl8.png" alt="Not Caries LL8" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                      <img id="img_cll_8_3" src="images/cl8.png" alt="Caries LL8" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          <!--Table body-->
                                        </table>
                                        <!--Table-->
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkW3e.png)

What can I do to make table in responsible view ?

Comment: You mentioned table with 17 columns and bootstrap grid system (rows and 12 columns). Those two are two different things. I am unclear which approach you want to take. Bootstrap responsive table will work with however many columns you have. It has nothing to do with the grid system.

Comment: you can use 6/6 grid and add 9 column in 1 column, but after doing that its looks bad

Comment: @DavidLiang I need to solve the attached image problem in table view